# how can i search data from 2 different table?

Tags: mysql, search, join

Below is my code.
model.

```
function get_search_conv() 
    {   

          $match = $this->input->post('search');
          $this->db->like('TextDecoded',$match);
          $query = $this->db->get('inbox');
          return $query->result();

    }
```

It works on one table,  but how can I search textDecoded in table 'inbox2'?
I tried with union, or join, but still not working. Anyone can help me?
thanks

Comment: I think you are doing in Codeigniter.

Comment: Can you confirm what language (PHP?) and frameworks you are using? E.g. is $this->db a `PDO` object?

Comment: `UNION` should be right. But remember, a `UNION` demands equal numbers of fields for all included queries.

Comment: oppss.. sorry, yes. i use codeigniter..

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
$sql="select * from inbox in1, inbox2 in2 
          where in1.TextDecoded like '%".$match."%' 
            or in2.TextDecoded like '%".$match."%'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
```

Another possible solution would be

```
function get_search_conv() 
{   

      $match = $this->input->post('search');
      $this->db->like('TextDecoded',$match);
      $this->db->or_like('TextDecoded',$match);
      $this->db->from('inbox,inbox2');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();

}
```

Here is your another answer. Avoid doing it using Active Record because you have to change the access modifiers to public for functions _compile_select() and _reset_select() in DB_active_rec.php. It's not a good idea

```
$sql = "SELECT TextDecoded FROM inbox where TextDecoded like '%".$match."%'
UNION 
SELECT TextDecoded FROM inbox2 where TextDecoded like '%".$match."%'"

$query = $this->db->query($sql);

return $query->result();
```

Comment: still not working. they repeat my data become hundreds.. n i cant search in my first table (inbox)

Comment: this will return duplicates. what you want ?

Comment: you can try with $this->db->distinct() in case of distinct results

Comment: i want to find the data from 2 tables and ignore the duplicates.. okay, can u help me, to use UNION in codeigniter? i try in mySql and working, but not in CI. like this "SELECT TextDecoded FROM inbox where TextDecoded like '%.$match.%' UNION SELECT TextDecoded FROM inbox2 where TextDecoded like '%.$match.%'". can you help me?

Comment: yes, thanks.. i forget to put " " between $match. haha